# Subtracting a number from an integer in android not working

Tags: android, math, integer

It must be something simple....

```
void CheckQty(long rowId, String manufacturer, String expires, String value, String category, String image, String valueother, Integer qty) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(qty<=1){
            deleteNote(rowId);
    }else{
        qty = Math.abs(qty)-1;
        updateNote(rowId, manufacturer, expires, value, category, image, valueother, qty);
    }
}
```

Update Note:

```
 public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String manufacturer, String expires, String value, String category, String image, String valueother, Integer qty) {

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_MANUFACTURER, manufacturer);
    args.put(KEY_EXPIRES, expires);
    args.put(KEY_VALUE, value);
    args.put(KEY_VALUE_OTHER, valueother);
    args.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    args.put(KEY_QTY, qty);
    args.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    //args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Initial value is taken from the database and passed to this function, it could be any number that the user puts in, but it does not seem to matter what the number is, the result is always 6

This only changes the 'qty' to 6

any help?

Comment: what's the initial value? also, what's in your updateNote(...) function?

Comment: Yeah, what's the value of qty before and after executing the qty = Math.abs(qty)-1; line of code?

Comment: Isn't this a *very* general question. Try to spend some time debugging rather than asking on every single bit which goes wrong to be solved for you - you'll learn more things this way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also get rid of the Math.abs call since you're already deleting it if qty < 0.  Change the line to just qty=qty-1.  Also, if you're just updating the quantity column, you don't need to update all the other values at the same time.

Comment: Turns out I needed to change the way I was getting 'qty'from: Integer qty = note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_QTY); to: Integer qty = Integer.parseInt(mQtyText.getText().toString());

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help/sounding board